# NOUISLIDER: Custom tooltip without changing value

Tags: javascript, nouislider

Is it possible to have formatted tooltip without modifying the value? Apparently, doing this would change the value to date.

```
tooltips: [true],
format: {
    from: Number,
    to: function(value) {
       var str_date = todate(arr[value].timestamp);
       return str_date; 
    }
}
```

I wanted to show date on the tooltip but I still need the integer value on my "on update" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the formatter (to/from) to the tooltips option instead of to the whole slider.

So: `tooltips: { to: function().... }`

Docs: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-tooltips